# Auto layout constraints on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout

I'm trying to apply this design I made with Sketch to my iOS app.
[image: Here's the design picture:]
[image]

[image]
On my storyboard it looks like the second picture.
However, when I run the app on an iPhone 5s (without any constraints) it looks like the third picture.
Which constraint should I add to the scene to make the card background image view centered as the concept; the icon imageView(in purple) centered X and Y; and all the other buttons and labels arranged in the sketch picture?
Thank you

Comment: You might want the Hello there message to constraint to the top of superview, not vertical align with the image. The image will just be at the center and the header will be at the top.

Comment: Yes I understand, thanks. But which constraints should I add to the background white card and the buttons?

Comment: the white card is contraints to the top, bottom, left, right of it's superview (which looks a main view for me). And button is constrainted to the white card with horizontal center and bottom constraint to the white card. and also add constraints to the button height. so, it doesn't need to be constraint with the image. Either that or >= to the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that the purple image with the building in it is small which is resizing the `UIImageView` and then dragging the "Hello There" label down to it.  First look at the Mode of your `UIImageView`.  I believe the mode you want is "Aspect Fill", but if that doesn't work try "Scale To Fill" as shown below.

[image]

Also the first constraint I would add after trying the above is a vertical top constraint between the "Hello There" label and the SuperView.  Then add 3 constraints around the UIImageView (top, left, right).